# Jquery dataTable change row color

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I am using JQuery datatable, 
I need to change the color of the row on the mouse over event (the highligthed row)
I tried:

```
table.display tr.even.row_selected td {
    background-color: red;
}

table.display tr.odd.row_selected td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9o891c5/2/)

Comment: It changes colour on hover. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: the class "row_selected" does not exist on your page. You need a little more JS to add the class to the selected row (assuming you are doing this from an onclick) and then your css should work.

Comment: tip: instead of using .even or .odd, use css
tr:nth-child(odd) or tr:nth-child(even)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this `CSS`:

```
table.display tbody tr:nth-child(even):hover td{
    background-color: red !important;
}

table.display tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

**[UPDATED jsFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9o891c5/7/)**

Comment: Yup thats the most acceptable approach, though it will make the .odd, .even classes useless, anyway I commented on him that use nth-child instead of making such classes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the JS snippets I write at the start of each project is to add some basic formatting to tables. Include this inside your *$(function() { ... });* block

```
    $('table tr').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    });
    $('table tr').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
```

Similarly, this bit will take away the hassle of adding odd/even markup to every row in the table, as your are building it

```
$('table').each(function() { $(this).find('tr:even').addClass('even'); });
$('table').each(function() { $(this).find('tr:odd').addClass('odd'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
table.display tbody .odd:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
}
table.display tbody .even:hover {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table.display tr.even td:hover{
    background-color: red;
}

table.display tr.odd td:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9o891c5/6/)**

```
#example tr td {
    height: 50px;
}
table.display tr.even td:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

table.display tr.odd td:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole row to change colour you can do this

```
#example tr td {
    height: 50px;
}
 table#example tr.even:hover td {
    background-color: red;
}

table#example tr.odd:hover td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/t2g9yft6/

Comment: because the css in jquery.datatable.css is more specifically targeting the td. in question. By using the id in my example this is making it the most specific selector and therefore having the style applied. You could always use !important to overrule any rule without worrying about how specific you are but I try to avoid that route as it can bite you later on. Here is a nice article to explain how you can work out which style will be applied http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa062706.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it? In CSS, td only changing color. This will be changing row color

Somthing like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
    $('table.display tr.even').hover(function(){
       $(this).css('background-color','#f00'); 
    });
    $('table.display tr.even').mouseout(function(){
       $(this).css('background-color','#f9f9f9'); 
    });    
} );
```

If it is not mandatory, remove it sorting_1 class name in first td. or can overwrite the css.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with the table css being overwritten if setting the styles with javascript, using the createdRow callback in the initialization of the table with jQuery worked:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({...

  createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    if (dataIndex%2 == 0) {
      $(row).attr('style', 'background-color: red;');
    } else {
      $(row).attr('style', 'background-color: blue;');  
    }
  }

});
```

see the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) for Datatable createdRow